# MAC address reversed after Windows 7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, networking, nvidia-nforce

I have a number of computers that are currently running Windows XP and I am installing a fresh version of Windows 7 on all of them. They all have the same mainboards with Nvidia on-board Ethernet NICs.

For several years, these computers used to ask our DHCP server for an IP adress with, e.g., this MAC: `00:13:8F:F5:C8:C2`. An IP address was handed out successfully.

After installing Windows 7 on *the very same computer* and booting into the OS, that machine is asking our DHCP server for a re-newal of it's IP adress, but this time using the **reverse** MAC: `C2:C8:F5:8F:13:00`.

Network (adapter) properties in Windows 7 also show the reverse address.

I have a workaround for this problem (I'm updating the DHCP server configuration file to handle the reverse MAC address for all newly installed PCs), but I'm curious to find the root cause. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can't help with that I'm afraid. Looks demonic.

Comment: It's the same mac, different endianness.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: I suspect the NVidia Ethernet NIC driver…

Just added a NIC from a different vendor to one of the system; that one is working perfectly fine.

I also noted that the non-reversed address (`00:13:8F...`) seems to be correct as this MAC prefix matches to AsRock (the vendor of the mainboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone, and this does indeed appear to be a buggy Nvidia NIC, and there is plenty of [other](https://www.illumos.org/issues/3387) [evidence](http://fluxsmith.blogspot.ie/2010/04/opensolaris-networking-nvidia-mcp67.html) around (on multiple OS's not just Windows), as well as people having to [work around](http://svn.linuxmce.org/trac/ticket/581) the issue.  There is even a [post](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/351983/?comment=2533201) on the geforce forums asking for advice on what to do with the same issue on a Gigabyte board.

Personally, I saw this while digging into a wake from LAN issue with an ASUS board and never got to the root cause.  I've since replaced that host, so the problem has effectively gone away for me - certainly very frustrating.  My gut feel is that this is either something that needs a BIOS level fix, or it's something that is hard coded and can't be changed by the motherboard vendors - seems like the only choice is to work around it on the OS side.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to order some additional PCI network cards from a different manufacturer to ease my mind…